# What happened to the nnDiag package?

Tags: r, package

I am looking to run diagnostics for categorical variable classifications in R.  I am particularly interested in getting User's and Producer's accuracy and kappa statistics. There used to be a package (nnDiag) in R that calculated all of these metrics.  It appears as if the package was removed from CRAN.  Does anyone know why it was discontinued and if there is a comparable package in R?  I am running R 3.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Caret does Cohen's Kappa and summary stats quite well.